# How to prevent script from bringing computer to near standstill

Tags: performance, batch-file, macros, imacros

I have a bat script which is rather complex and runs every 15 minutes. It opens a browser, runs an iMacro to sign in and download a file, closes the browser, extracts the file, initiates a javascript which verifies that the downloaded file is more recent than the one downloaded 15 minutes earlier, opens Excel, imports the downloaded file, triggers a very involved VB Script, exports a csv file, closes Excel, opens a new browser, logs in to a 2nd site, uploads the csv file and closes the browser again.

Meanwhile I'm doing my job, which requires many browser tabs open in several different browsers, and web development software.

While the script is running, my computer will frequently come to a near standstill, preventing me from doing any other work - presumedly because the CPU usage is maxed out. Not only can I not do other work, but my script frequently fails to complete because the browser is so slow it times out before the page loads.

Task Manager tells me that my CPU usage while running the script is 98-100% and I'm using 7 out of 8 MB of RAM. Obviously, I'm pushing my computer to its limits. Is there anything I can do to help minimize the slow down, such as allocate some RAM, partition my hard drive, make a sacrifice to the processor gods, etc.? My computer is a 64-bit running Windows 7 Pro with 8MB of RAM and a 3.00 GHz processor.  I can't get a new computer but I can probably ask for additional RAM if it would help.

I don't know very much about performance optimization, so any suggestions are welcome. I can't stop using the script, run it less often, or run it on a different computer.

Comment: 8MB of RAM? anyway if that was 7 out of 8 GB of RAM then probably it would help adding more.

Comment: Bit difficult to say without having access to your scripts, data, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In a script that loops to repeat a task immediately then the CPU usage will rise to very high levels.

Using `timeout` or `ping` to generate a delay between loops reduces the CPU usage.

Comment: I'm using Windows Task Scheduler to run it every 15 minutes. Is that better or worse?

Comment: That is a good solution too as long as the script finishes in 15 minutes.  Your script must run CPU intensive tasks or is running too many tasks at once.